# Использование property

Tags: c++

Люди помогите! Поясните, что это код делает?

```
__property int SizeX  = { read=FSizeX, write=SetSizeX };
__property int SizeY  = { read=FSizeY, write=SetSizeY }; 
__property int Vy  = { read=Fvy, write=SetVy };
```

Answer (score 7):

*На вопрос вам, в принципе, уже ответили, но попробую разъяснить некоторые подробности.*

Вообще говоря, `__property` - это некоторая попытка нарастить стандартные возможности C++  платформо-зависимым способом.

Конкретно в C++ Builder следующие фрагменты кода будут эквивалентными *(разве что в первом случае ответственность за генерацию геттеров / сеттеров переносится на компилятор*).

```
__property int SizeX  = { read=FSizeX, write=SetSizeX };

public:
    void SetSizeX(int NewSizeX) { SizeX = NewSizeX; }
    int FSizeX() const { return SizeX; }
private:
    int SizeX;
```

У использования `__property` есть только одно обозримое преимущество, которое заключается в избавлении от необходимости писать *boilerplate* код для геттеров и сеттеров. Ну и, плюс, мы получаем некоторую структуризацию кода, когда все *property-like* члены класса оказываются в одном и том же месте.

Недостатков же **намного больше** - в первую очередь, **полная непереносимость такого кода на другие платформы**. Сюда стоит добавить еще неочевидность генерации методов `GetProperty` в плане константности, отсутствие поддержки семантики переноса (`&&`) из стандарта C++0x, сложность написания нетривиальных геттеров и сеттеров, поддерживающих *lazy-loading* и т.д.

Лично у меня, например, вопроса *"использовать `__property` или нет"* просто не возникает, поскольку недостатков, к сожалению, намного больше, нежели преимуществ. То же самое, кстати говоря, относится к платформо-специфичным вещам типа `_CrtSetReportMode`, которые, если и используются, то должны быть строго отделены `ifdef'ами`.

---

**P.S.**

Если еще немного порассуждать насчет `__property`, то аналогичное расширение существует в [Microsoft C++/CLI.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z974bes2(v=vs.71).aspx) Но, в отличие от C++ Builder, там необходимость использования `__property` *обусловлена нативной поддержкой свойств* в C# (т.е разработчикам CLI Runtime просто необходимо было каким-то образом продублировать этот же механизм в биндинге для C++).

---

**P.P.S.**

Также отмечу, что проблема *property-like* членов класса и необходимости соответствующей конвенции хорошо решена в [**Google C++ Code Style,**](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) где четко определен способ оформления членов класса вида `get_value()`.

Comment: >аналогичное расширение существует в Microsoft C++/CLI. Но, в отличие от C++ Builder, там необходимость использования __property обусловлена нативной поддержкой свойств в C# (т.е разработчикам CLI Runtime просто необходимо было каким-то образом продублировать этот же механизм в биндинге для C++).

 Насколько я знаю, языки .NET необязательно должны поддерживать свойства. Свойства неявно генерируют функции get_Property и set_Property. К тому же, свойства в VС++ работают без использования C++\CLI.

Comment: @GLmonster *Понятное дело, что необязательно.* Однако, если мы хотим, чтобы на основании кода `C++ CLI` был сгенерирован объект со свойствами *(чтобы, например, обращаться к этим свойствам из шарпового кода)*, то выхода, кроме использования `__property`, у нас просто нет.

--------

В `VC++`, в принципе, можно использовать `__declspec(property(...))` для подстановки геттеров и сеттеров вместо обычного вызова `class.member`, но это уже слабо относится к заданному вопросу и, честно говоря, является очередной невнятной и специфичной надстройкой для языка.

Comment: >Однако, если мы хотим, чтобы на основании кода C++ CLI был сгенерирован объект со свойствами (чтобы, например, обращаться к этим свойствам из шарпового кода), то выхода, кроме использования __property, у нас просто нет.

 На практике не пробовал, но теоретически можно, если назвать функции get_Value и set_Value, а в C# обращаться как Value.

Comment: @GLmonster Ну в примере `MSDN` как раз такие вызовы и помечены с помощью `__property`. Не знаю насчет без `__property`, но с ним точно работает. *Как-нибудь проверю.*

Answer (score 1):

Это код именно на С++. Я сам писал такой многократно. Разработчик не дает возможности пользователю обращаться к полям `Fx` непосредственно: чтение поля - через свойство, а изменение его - через функцию `SetX()`. Поле и функция оформляются в классе как `private`, а `property` - как `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код видимо не на C++. Но ясно что он объявляет два три поля и задаёт соответственно для каждого по get и set методу. Это из ООП (на случай, если вы не знаете, что такое property).

Comment: @BuilderC, можно поподробнее? Я что-то такого не встречал. Это примочки какого-то компилятора или общие вещи?

Comment: Поподробнее: А.Я.Архангельский,"Программирование в С++Builder 6",М.,"Бином", 2002 г, с.524.

Comment: Да-да, лежал у меня такой кирпич. 

Это именно ему характерные штучки?

Comment: Не совсем "именно Билдеру". Вспомните, что в С++ возможны ф-ции, которые возвращают ссылку на переменную, и которые, поэтому, можно использовать в виде F(x) = n, т.е. в операторе присваивания поставить слева. Мне кажется, что их тут и используют. 
Впрочем, хорошо бы уважаемого @Котик-хочет-кушать спросить: он пограмотнее меня будет.

Comment: @BuilderC Всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

property в C++ сейчас можно использовать в таком варианте:

```
    class Proper {
        int field;
        int mass[2][2];
    public:
        void set_field(int val) {
            field = val;
        }
        int get_field() {
            return field;
        }
        void set_mass(int row, int col, int val) {
            mass[row][col] = val;
        }
        int get_mass(int row, int col) {
            return mass[row][col];
        }
    
        __declspec (property (get = get_field, put = set_field)) int field_property;
        __declspec (property (get = get_mass, put = set_mass)) int mass_property[][];
    };

int main()
{
    Proper test_property;
    test_property.field_property = 10;
    cout <<"test_property.my_property= " << test_property.field_property <<endl;

    test_property.mass_property[0][0] = 1;
    test_property.mass_property[0][1] = 2;
    test_property.mass_property[1][0] = 3;
    test_property.mass_property[1][1] = 4;

    cout << "test_property.mass_property= \n" << test_property.mass_property[0][0] <<"  " 
        << test_property.mass_property[0][1] <<  endl<< test_property.mass_property[1][0] << "  "
        << test_property.mass_property[1][1] << endl;
}
```